# How to pass a tensor variable to feed_dict?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network

I have basic neural network which has a function run(). which takes the input and provides the output of the neural network. In the function body, I would like to `feed_dict` weights when running a session to calculate the output. Since these weights are `tf.compat.v1.variable` I am having an error `ValueError: Setting an array element with sequence`

I have initially thought it was my input that is causing the error and hence, I have made sure it has same dimensions as weights to use `tf.multiply` and since the error continued, I made sure to convert the numpy array into a tensor object hoping that might be causing the error. But ti still does not work.

```py
def run(self, carollis_input):
        self.normalization(carollis_input)
        c_in = np.array(carollis_input)
        c_input = tf.compat.v1.convert_to_tensor(c_in, tf.float64)
        #'finding the output of the input layer'
        #with tf.Session() as sess1_2:
        input_weight = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=(self.neurons, 1))
        input_bias = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=(self.neurons, 1))
        hidden_weight = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=(self.neurons, 1))
        hidden_bias =tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=(self.neurons, 1))
        output_weight = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=(4, 1))
        output_bias = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=(self.neurons, 1))

        knowledge_input = tf.add(tf.multiply(c_input, input_weight), input_bias)
        with tf.Session() as ses1:
            ses1.run(knowledge_input, feed_dict={input_weight: self.weight_in, input_bias:self.bias_in})
        knowledge_hidden = tf.nn.leaky_relu(knowledge_input, alpha=0.01) 
        #'calculating the output of hidden layer'
        knowledge_hidden_output = 3.14*(tf.add(tf.multiply(knowledge_hidden, hidden_weight), hidden_bias))#input function of hidden layer
        knowledge_hidden_out = tf.nn.leaky_relu(knowledge_hidden_output, alpha=0.01, name='leaky_relu')

        with tf.Session() as ses2:
            ses2.run(knowledge_hidden_out, feed_dict={hidden_weight: self.weight_hid, hidden_bias:self.bias_hid})
        #'calculating the input of output layer'
        tf.reshape(knowledge_hidden_out, [4, 2])#for quadrant method
        in_out = tf.add(tf.multiply(knowledge_hidden_out, output_weight), output_bias)
        with tf.Session() as ses3:
            ses3.run(in_out, feed_dict={output_weight: self.weight_out, output_bias: self.bias_out})
        #'finding the softmax output of the neurons'
        softmax_output = np.array(4)
        softmax_output = self.out_softmax(in_out)  # this gives the softmax output and stores it in the newly created array
        return softmax_output
```

After going through other answers , I believe that error might be cause because I was trying to feed in a tensor variable i.e. weights and biases to the feed_dict. If thats the problem, how can i solve it, please kindly help me. The exact error is

```
File "/home/microbot/catkin_ws/src/spider/spider_control/knowledge_transfer.py", line 85, in run
    ses1.run(knowledge_input, feed_dict={input_weight: self.weight_in, input_bias:self.bias_in})
  File "/home/microbot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 950, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/microbot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1142, in _run
    np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
  File "/home/microbot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

EDIT:
The weights are initialized inside the class initialiser i.e.

```
def __init__(self, neurons, layers):
        self.neurons = neurons
        self.layers =  layers
        self.weight_initer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0.0, stddev=0.01)
        self.weight_in = tf.get_variable(name="Weight_input", dtype=tf.float64, shape=[self.neurons, 1], initializer=self.weight_initer)
        self.weight_initer1 = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=1.0, stddev=0.01)
        self.weight_hid = tf.get_variable(name="Weight_hidden", dtype=tf.float64, shape=[self.neurons, 1], initializer=self.weight_initer1)
        self.weight_initer2 = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=2.0, stddev=0.01)
        self.weight_out = tf.get_variable(name="Weight_output", dtype=tf.float64, shape=[4, 2], initializer=self.weight_initer2)
        self.bias_initer =tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0.1, stddev=0.01)
        self.bias_in  =tf.get_variable(name="Bias_input", dtype=tf.float64, shape=[self.neurons, 1], initializer=self.bias_initer)
        self.bias_initer1 =tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0.2, stddev=0.01)
        self.bias_hid = tf.get_variable(name="Bias_hidden", dtype=tf.float64, shape=[self.neurons, 1], initializer=self.bias_initer1)
        self.bias_initer2 =tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0.3, stddev=0.01)
        self.bias_out = tf.get_variable(name="Bias_output", dtype=tf.float64, shape=[4, 1], initializer=self.bias_initer2)
```

Although now I have been having two different confusing, one with respective to scope of the graph and other to the weight initialising. Since I have defined the weight tensors in the initialiser, would this be the defaul graph and the graph that i am trying to build inside the run function be secondary ?

Comment: You cannot pass a TensorFlow variable as a value in a `feed_dict`, you can only pass NumPy arrays (or Python sequences, like a list). If anything, you would have to first get the value of the variable (e.g. `weight_val = sess.run(self.weight_in)`) and then pass that value in the `feed_dict`. But that does not make sense either here, because you have created a session, so variables do not have any value yet (in fact, trying to access the value of a variable would cause an error because they have not been initialised).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Can you please look into the edit part of the answer ? As I have already initialised weights in the class initialiser, what does it mean by "weights have not been initialised" ? can you please provide me a bit more clarity with respect to that. Thank you.